# Convert System::String^ to int32 in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, datagridview, casting

I have `dataGridView` and I need to check `dataGridView->Rows[j]->Cells[i]->Value`. If its >0 make some work, else - do nothing. I tried

```
int x =  Int32::Parse(dataGridView1->Rows[j]->Cells[i]->Value->ToString());
if(x > 0 )count++;
```

but have Format exception,  Input string was not in a correct format.

```
int x =  Convert::ToInt32(dataGridView1->Rows[j]->Cells[i]->Value->ToString());
```

also Format exception, Input string was not in a correct format.

```
int x = safe_cast<int>(dataGridView1->Rows[j]->Cells[i]->Value);
```

InvalidCast exception, specified cast is not valid.

What I'm doing wrong?

Update: The right way is

```
double x =  Convert::ToDouble(dataGridView1->Rows[j]->Cells[i]->Value);
```